# Dibujar lineas dentro de un circulo en Java

Tags: java, java-awt

Hola necesito dibujar lineas y mini circulos solamente dentro de un circulo, el problema es que al darle click debo crear 2 mini circulos dentro del circulo mas grande y esos 2 mini circulos se tienen que conectar y crear una linea, . Tendria que ser algo asi :[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private double radius = 0.0;
private double diameter ;


public DrawCircle() {
    addMouseListener(this);
    setSize(600,700);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

//Dibujando circulo
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D Circle = (Graphics2D)g;
    Circle.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10.f));
    Circle.setColor(Color.black);
    radius = 100;
    diameter = radius * 2 ;
    Circle.drawOval(200,300, (int) diameter, (int) diameter);
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DrawCircle();

}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e ) {
Graphics g = getGraphics();
if (e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawOval(e.getX(),e.getY(),5,5);
}

        
    }
```

Comment: Veo que lo que has conseguido hasta ahora sería que dibujase el círculo pequeño al hacer click. Lo que necesitarías es añadirle un estado a la clase, que supiese si estás haciendo el primer click (dibujar circulo) o el segundo click (dibujar circulo y línea). En tu manejador de eventos, si estás pulsando la primera vez, debería pintar el círculo y guardar la posición que se ha hecho click. La segunda vez, pintar el círculo como en el primer caso y trazar la línea desde la posición del click actual a la posición del click que guardaste previamente.